# MySQL query killing my server

Tags: mysql

Looking at this query there's got to be something bogging it down that I'm not noticing.  I ran it for 7 minutes and it only updated 2 rows.

```
//set product count for makes
$tru->query->run(array(
    'name' => 'get-make-list',
    'sql' => 'SELECT id, name FROM vehicle_make',
    'connection' => 'core'
));
while($tempMake = $tru->query->getArray('get-make-list')) {
    $tru->query->run(array(
        'name' => 'update-product-count',
        'sql' => 'UPDATE vehicle_make SET product_count = (
            SELECT COUNT(product_id) FROM taxonomy_master WHERE v_id IN (
                SELECT id FROM vehicle_catalog WHERE make_id = '.$tempMake['id'].'
        )
) WHERE id = '.$tempMake['id'],
        'connection' => 'core'
    ));
}
```

I'm sure this query can be optimized to perform better, but I can't think of how to do it.

vehicle_make = 45 rows

taxonomy_master = 11,223 rows

vehicle_catalog = 5,108 rows

All tables have appropriate indexes

**UPDATE:** I should note that this is a 1-time script so overhead isn't a big deal as long as it runs.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicle_make` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `product_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=46 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `taxonomy_master` (
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `v_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_requirement` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_sellable` enum('True','False') DEFAULT 'True',
  `programming_override` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`v_id`),
  KEY `idx2` (`product_id`),
  KEY `idx3` (`v_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicle_catalog` (
  `v_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v_make` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `make_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v_model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v_year` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`v_id`,`v_make`,`v_model`,`v_year`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx` (`v_make`,`v_model`,`v_year`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx2` (`v_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Update:** The successful query to get what I needed is here....

```
SELECT 
        m.id,COUNT(t.product_id) AS CountOf
        FROM taxonomy_master             t
            INNER JOIN vehicle_catalog   v ON t.v_id=v.id
            INNER JOIN vehicle_make      m ON v.make_id=m.id
        GROUP BY m.id;
```

Comment: post your tables/columns and each existing index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without the tables/columns this is my best guess from reverse engineering the given queries:

```
UPDATE m
    SET product_count =COUNT(t.product_id)
    FROM taxonomy_master             t
        INNER JOIN vehicle_catalog   v ON t.v_id=v.id
        INNER JOIN vehicle_make      m ON v.make_id=m.id
    GROUP BY m.name
```

The given code loops over each make, and then runs a query the counts for each.  My answer just does them all in one query and should be a lot faster.

have an index for each of these:

```
vehicle_make.id      cover on name
vehicle_catalog.id   cover make_id
taxonomy_master.v_id
```

**EDIT**

give this a try:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CountsOf (
     id int(11) NOT NULL
     , CountOf int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
);

INSERT INTO CountsOf 
        (id, CountOf )
    SELECT 
        m.id,COUNT(t.product_id) AS CountOf
        FROM taxonomy_master             t
            INNER JOIN vehicle_catalog   v ON t.v_id=v.id
            INNER JOIN vehicle_make      m ON v.make_id=m.id
        GROUP BY m.id;

UPDATE taxonomy_master,CountsOf
    SET taxonomy_master.product_count=CountsOf.CountOf 
WHERE taxonomy_master.id=CountsOf.id;
```

Comment: Good thought with it all in one query.... throws an SQL syntax error near "FROM taxonomy_master t INNER JOIN...."

Comment: Nice query...... but it throws the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM vehicle_make mm INNER JOIN (SELECT m.id,' at line 3

Comment: I'm executing it via PHPMyAdmin on my server

Answer (score 0):

instead of using nested query , 
you can  separated this query to 2 or 3 queries,

and in php insert the result of the inner query to the out query ,

its   faster !

Answer (score 0):

@haim-evgi Separating the queries will not increase the speed significantly, it will just shift the load from the DB server to the Web server and create overhead of moving data between the two servers.

I am not sure with the appropriate indexes you run such query 7 minutes. Could you please show the table structure of the tables involved in these queries.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need the following indices:

1. INDEX BTREE('make_id') on vehicle_catalog
2. INDEX BTREE('v_id') on taxonomy_master